# How can I use "stat_compare_means" on the same plot multiple times?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

as the title suggests I have a plot where I took measurements over time of 3 different groups (2 control and 1 treatment group) in a data frame like this:

| Treatment | Value | Repetition | Timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control1 | Value1 | 1 | 1 |
| Control1 | Value2 | 2 | 1 |
| Control1 | Value3 | 3 | 1 |
| Control1 | Value1 | 1 | 2 |
| Control1 | Value2 | 2 | 2 |
| Control1 | Value3 | 3 | 2 |
| Control2 | Value1 | 1 | 1 |
| Control2 | Value2 | 2 | 1 |
| Control2 | Value3 | 3 | 1 |
| Control2 | Value1 | 1 | 2 |
| Control2 | Value2 | 2 | 2 |
| Control2 | Value3 | 3 | 2 |
| Treatment1 | Value1 | 1 | 1 |
| Treatment1 | Value2 | 2 | 1 |
| Treatment1 | Value3 | 3 | 1 |
| Treatment1 | Value1 | 1 | 2 |
| Treatment1 | Value2 | 2 | 2 |
| Treatment1 | Value3 | 3 | 2 |

(In actuality I have more Repetitions and Timepoints, but I think this is sufficient to understand what I mean).

I now have a plot that looks roughly like this:

[image: img 1]

The code I used was:

```
plot <- ggplot(subset(data_frame, 
                      Treatment %in% c("Control1", "Control2", "Treatment1")), 
               aes(x=Timepoint, y=Value, fill=Treatment)) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=Timepoint, y=Value, color=Treatment), 
               geom="point", fun=mean, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  stat_summary(aes(x=Timepoint, y=Value, color=Treatment), 
               geom="line", fun=mean, show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=Timepoint, y=Value, color=Treatment), 
               geom="errorbar", fun = "mean", fun.min = "min", fun.max = "max", 
               width=0.2, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Next, I want to compare the means of Treatment 1 with Control 2 (not Control 1, this has experimental reasons) for each time point individually and add the significant value (either p-value or "*") into the plot using a wilcoxon test (e.g. Treatment 1 vs Control 2 on Timepoint 1, and the same for Timepoint 2). Usually I use `stat_compare_means()` for this but I can't get it to work here.
Here is an example of what it should look like where I did it manually:

[image: img 2]

I calculated the statistics elsewhere and then added it as a `geom_text()` on height y=1 onto the plot, which is tedious and there must be a way to "automate" this.

Comment: This is not that much easy as muiltiple comparisons are not statistically the same as n times repeated comparisons done on the same plot. There are corrections for multiple comparisons. See Bonferroni correction for instance

Comment: My short comment: Don't do it. Adding to above comment, stat_compare_means will probably not allow for this. If you have multiple, arguably arbitrary comparisons, this sounds like an exploratory approach (for which mere value visualisation -without the p-values- should be enough, in my opinion). Instead, if you must, add a table with all those p-values next to your plot.